# Getting 404 error on running Restful web Service in java

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am trying to create a restful web service in java. Whenever I am trying to run it I am getting 404 error and I am not able to figure out why!

I am referring [JavaTPoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/jax-rs-file-download-example) for this.

This is how my project looks like-

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"   
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">  
     <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
        <init-param>  
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>  
            <param-value>com.javatpoint.rest</param-value>  
        </init-param>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
      </servlet>  
      <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
      </servlet-mapping>  
    </web-app>
```

**FileDownloadService.java**

```
package com.javatpoint.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/files")
public class FileDownloadService {
    @GET
    @Path("/txt")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String getFile() {
        String response = null;
        response = "<?xml version='1.0'?><hello>Hello xml</hello>";
        return response;
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="rest/files/txt">Download Text File</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting following response-

[image]

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: can you try href=http://localhost:8080/rest/files/txt; Am assuming you are running your local server on port 8080

Comment: Thanks.. it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify the full path to your api

```
<a href="[full path to your servlet container]/rest/files/txt">Download Text File</a>
```

Comment: Glad I could help, please accept the answer if it solved your issue